# Meteor - JQuery Version Conflict, how to handle?

Tags: jquery, meteor

I am trying to implement a template bought from "themeforest",template name "Katalaya". The template comes with JQuery version "jQuery v2.1.1". However Meteor by default has jQuery JavaScript Library v1.11.2. Looks like the Meteor 1.1.0.3 by default has the lower Jquery version.

Now how do we update the Meteor's Jquery version to 2.1.1 ? Anyone done this before? Was there any other impact doing so?

Any help would be appreciated.

Jay

Comment: jQuery 1.11.2 is newer than 2.1.1, why would you go backwards? 2.1.2 would be an equivalent version to 1.11.2, not an upgrade, but you lose IE8 support in the process.

Answer (score 0):

The theme should work with meteor's jquery, You should be looking into modifying the theme jquery (removing it) It's not easy to migrate themeforest themes to meteor. But in general you should modify the theme to fit to meteor

Answer (score 0):

Keep both and try using `jQuery.noConflict();` https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/